# How to render ListView items in sections by (section-id) from JSON file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this JSON array of objects:

json

```
[
   {
      "section-id": "1",
      "section-title": "Section 1",
      "title": "item1"
   },
   {
      "section-id": "1",
      "section-title": "Section 1",
      "title": "item2"
   },
   {
      "section-id": "2",
      "section-title": "Section 2",
      "title": "item3"
   },
   {
      "section-id": "2",
      "section-title": "Section 2",
      "title": "item4"
   },
   {
      "section-id": "2",
      "section-title": "Section 2",
      "title": "item5"
   }
]
```

I want to make a ListView in **Flutter** to render list items in this order:
[Open Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hknGI.jpg)

- Header (only once)
- **[Section 1]**
- item1
- item2
- **[Section 2]**
- item3
- item4
- item5

Comment: So you have no idea how to parse Json or store data according to `section-id`? There is a bunch of *how to parse Json* in SO...

Comment: i  know how to parse json but i want to make my listview show sections like in image included acording to `section-id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check condition inside ListView.builder + put the header out.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Map<String, String>> entities = [
    {
      "section-id": "1",
      "section-title": "Section 1",
      "title": "item1",
    },
    {
      "section-id": "1",
      "section-title": "Section 1",
      "title": "item2",
    },
    {
      "section-id": "2",
      "section-title": "Section 2",
      "title": "item3",
    },
    {
      "section-id": "2",
      "section-title": "Section 2",
      "title": "item4",
    },
    {
      "section-id": "2",
      "section-title": "Section 2",
      "title": "item5",
    }
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Header', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                Widget item = Text(entities[index]['title']);

                if (index == 0 ||
                    entities[index - 1]['section-id'] != entities[index]['section-id']) {
                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(entities[index]['section-title']),
                      item,
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return item;
                }
              },
              itemCount: entities.length,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, pls upvote the answer if it's helped you. The stackoverflow rating system doesn't count approved answer in specific tag rating, only votes.

Comment: Sorry @kherel my reputations are less than 15, i'm newbie here

Comment: No problem then. Thank anyway. Everybody was a newbie. Have a nice day